# Finding $g_i$ such that $f_i(n) = Θ(g_i(n))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to understand the following question:

For each of the following functions $f_i$, find the simplest function $g_i$ such that $f_i(n) = Θ(g_i(n))$

two examples:

(b) $f_2(n) = n + n * log(n) + \sqrt{n}$

(c) $f_3(n) = log_2(n^{20}) + (log_2n)^{10}$

I understand the chain of dominance, such that $n*log(n)$ and $(log_2n)^{10}$ are the two dominant elements of each function respectively. So they could upper bound $f$, but I don't understand how to find lower bound and then what to do with the upper/lower bound once I've found it. I understand finding equivalence classes, but not then creating functions to represent them.

Any hints or explanations of how to go about this question would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you see that $n + n \log n  + \sqrt{n} \geq n \log n$?

Comment: Oh, of course, and it's the dominant element. So $g(n) = n log n$?
And for (c), $g(n) = (log_2n)^{10}$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will figure it out now yourself. Good luck!